# How to add a late fee automatically to a monthly payment

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I'm working on a smart contract that allows users to pay for monthly subscriptions like Netflix, Amazon, etc...

the function that allows user to pay their subscriptions is working fine, but I want to add an additional feature so when the user misses his monthly payment the amount that they should pay should increase.

How can I implement that inside the below function?

What do you think about the payment? it's secure enough?

```
 struct Plan {
        address merchant;
        address token;
        uint amount;
        uint frequency;
      }
      struct Subscription {
        address subscriber;
        uint start;
        uint nextPayment;
      }
      mapping(uint => Plan) public plans;
      mapping(address => mapping(uint => Subscription)) public subscriptions;
    
    function pay(address subscriber, uint planId) external {
        Subscription storage subscription = subscriptions[subscriber][planId];
        Plan storage plan = plans[planId];
        require(
          subscription.subscriber != address(0), 
          'this subscription does not exist'
        );
        require(
          block.timestamp > subscription.nextPayment,
          'not due yet'
        );
   require(msg.value >= plan.monthlyPayment, "monthly payment not correct");
     
        emit PaymentSent(
          subscriber,
          plan.merchant, 
          plan.amount, 
          planId, 
          block.timestamp
        );
        subscription.nextPayment = subscription.nextPayment + 4 weeks;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must change the `Subscription` `struct`. Instead of storing `nextPayment` you must store `lastPayment`. Considering you already have a `plan` `frequency` which I suppose is how often a user must pay, there is no need of manually incrementing the next payment by 4 weeks. Furthermore, with lastPayment we can calculate how many payments a user has missed.

```
struct Plan {
    address merchant;
    address token;
    uint amount;
    uint frequency;
}

struct Subscription {
    address subscriber;
    uint start;
    uint lastPayment;
}

mapping(uint => Plan) public plans;
mapping(address => mapping(uint => Subscription)) public subscriptions;

uint feeIncrement = 10**16;

function pay(address subscriber, uint planId) payable external {
    Subscription storage subscription = subscriptions[subscriber][planId];
    Plan storage plan = plans[planId];

    require(subscription.subscriber != address(0), "This subscription doesn't exist.");

    //For a payment to be due, the last payment timestamp + how long to wait for another payment must be greater than current time. 
    require(subscription.lastPayment + plan.frequency >= block.timestamp, "Payment is not due.");

    //Amount of payments due. Calculated by dividing elapsed time from last payment by how often a payment must be made.
    //Solidity automatically floors this value (rounds it down).
    uint duePayments = ((block.timestamp - subscription.lastPayment) / plan.frequency);

    //Payment must be equal to the number of monthly payments + fee * due payments. We subtract the fee at the end as if only 1
    //payment is due, we don't want the user to pay the fee. feeIncrement in this case would be 0.01 ETH fee per missed payment.
    require(msg.value >= (((plan.monthlyPayment + feeIncrement) * duePayments) - feeIncrement), "Payment value is incorrect.");
 
    emit PaymentSent(
      subscriber,
      plan.merchant, 
      plan.amount, 
      planId, 
      block.timestamp
    );

    //We update the last payment parameter. REMEMBER: this must NOT be set to the current timestamp. As duePayments is rounded down,
    //setting lastPayment to current timestamp would enable users to skip payments by paying slightly before the start of another payment.
    subscription.lastPayment += (plan.frequency * duePayments);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I just want to mention something about the LastPayment that you suggest changing instead of the next payment. I have another function called getSubscriptions( I added it to my post) that from where I update the next payment for each user.